# Show PHP result in Jscript Pop-up

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

i want a user to be able to check a number in the database by putting in some details. This number would then be shown in a javascript alert.

I have the index page with the user input as seen below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkpna.php",
            type: "POST"})
    }

    function show_alert()
    {
        alert(check())
    }


</script>


<form action="#" method="get" class="formubuntu" onSubmit="return submitForm()">
    <p>Check Pallet PNA Number &nbsp;<input name="lpn" id="lpn_0" type="text" style="border-top-left-radius: 4px 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px 4px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" value="Pallet LPN">
    &nbsp;<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="art-button" onclick="show_alert()"></p>
</form>
```

and the checkpna.php which checks the specific details in the DB:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if($_GET['submit'] == "Submit")
{
    $lpn = $_GET["lpn"];

}

$values = array();

$query = "select serial_number from t_container where container_number = '".$lpn."';";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo stripslashes($row['serial_number']);
    }
}

else {
    echo "NO RESULTS";
}

?>
```

however i am getting a popup that says undefined. what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `check` does not return anything (hence `undefined`).

If you do `return $.ajax()` it *does* return something, but what? It returns a `Promise`. A promise is a container for a future value, a value we don't have yet. The reason we don't have the value yet is because the request hasn't completed yet, it only just started.

You can change your code to:

```
function check() {
    return $.ajax(/* .. */);
}
function show_alert() {
    check().done(function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });
}
```

---

There are some serious problems with your PHP code. It *works*, but it's not secure. Read up on SQL Injection and look at validating your input (you check `submit`, but not `lpn`).

Comment: thanks for the response. when using the suggested method above i get an error stating that 'submit' is an undefined variable in checkpna.php?

Comment: The ajax request you're making doesn't automatically send the contents of the form. You have to pass in the relevant parameters. See the `$.ajax` doc on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "checkpna.php",
        type: "POST"})
     .done(function( data ) {
        alert(data);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alert immediately, you have to wait until you receive the answer to your Ajax request from the server. Just add a callback function to do this, when the result arrives.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function check()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkpna.php",
            type: "POST",
            complete: function(return) {
                alert(return);
            }
        })
    }

    function show_alert()
    {
        check();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for ajax request you need a callback when success and alert from that callback

From [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> success Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR
>   jqXHR ) A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function
>   gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server,
>   formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the
>   status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of
>   jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each
>   function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_alert()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "checkpna.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kuntau the above code returns an error in the alert instead of a result. it is now complaining that the "submit" is an undefined variable in checkpna.php